# нужен редирект при отсутствии cookie

Tags: apache, cookie, redirect, auth

в кратце так: при заходе на URI /report , нужно чтобы apache проверял есть ли кука "имя куки" , если есть то пропускать на этот URI , если нету то делать редирект на /auth , там приложение которое выполнит авторизацию и выдаст нужную куки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/report /?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} <Куки>=([^;]+)
RewriteRule .* http://site.ru/auth
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую! напишу результат

Comment: попробовал ругается на /?$ , убрал эти символы, вроде как работает, когда есть кука это правило перезаписи игнориться, когда нету срабатывает. А для чего нужны были эти символы, насколько они важны? Ещё раз спасибо за ваш ответ!